# Service - Component interaction in Angular 4 via Broadcast event

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am hitting a service which fetches the data from the server. Once the data has arrived I wish to process it into a proper structure and then the refined result is what I wish to store in another service. For sharing this data from the data-processor function to the service I wish to use an event.

Is there a way I can do it. I have used Broadcast event of RxJS.

Answer (score 1):

Your service, which fetches data from the server, probably returns an observable.
You can subscribe to an observable using the
`.subscribe((data: any) => { // your refiner code });` syntax.

Since you are alreday working with observables, try to use another observable to communicate with your second service.
Please provide more information about your code so I can help properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control on the second service, you could make use of a Subject. For instance

```js
   this.myservice1.fetch()
    .map(data=>yourTransformFunction(data))
    //now link the output of this observable (the data received, error
    //and complete signal) into the "entrance" of the service's subject.
    .subscribe(this.myservice2.mySubject)
```

And in myservice2:

```js
mySubject = new Subject<any>()

constructor() {
  …
  this.mySubject.subscribe(…/*do the storage, update a store, whatever you like…*/)
  …
}
```